# Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows - shrinking D partition instead of C

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I have a qustion. In almost every guide I've read about dual boot Win/Ubuntu, the first step is to shrink C: partition. My PC has 2 partitions: C (for Windows) and D (for data and programs). Is there a possibility to shrink D and install on it's space? Or do I need to interfere to C? And does installing Ubuntu will destroy Recovery Windows partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Shrinking D is okay too

As long as D is not a separate physical drive, it does not matter if you shrink C or D. Even if D in a different physical drive, you can Install Ubuntu there as well. The process would be slightly different as you will have to use the advanced installation method call **Something Else** to select the second drive and manually setup the system partition for Ubuntu.

As long as C and D are two partitions in a single physical drive, and you shrink D to make space for Ubuntu system partition, the standard installation process should find that empty space and offer to install Ubuntu there.

Hope this helps